# Powershell or CMD script to test if volume exists on Server A and if it doesn't, try Server B

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am attempting to Robocopy files over to an active/passive cluster.  I would like to write a script that will allow me to Robocopy by somehow testing to see if the volume exists on Server A, if not, then Robocopy to Server B.  Right now, I have the servers hardcoded so if the cluster nodes failover, I would need to go through each Robocopy script and change the server name.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? You've told us what you're trying to do but not what your question exactly is? Are you also able to show us code you've completed for us to look at?

Comment: I apologize.  So right now, I only have 
`robocopy <source> <destination> /e /xx /xo`
Is there a way to test if the volume is located on Server A?  If it's not there, then Robocopy to Server B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `Test-Path`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is perfect.  Thank you!